# Can I reference the Object I'm currently inside of

Tags: java, angularjs, oop, session, jpa

Newbie here. So I'm working with java persistence to make a crude wedding website that maps guests (invites) to weddings. As each invite can attend multiple weddings, I've made a method that maps over them (using Java streams) and returns weddings they are associated with like so:

```
@RequestMapping("/invites")
public List<Wedding> invitesList(HttpSession session) {
    String email = (String) session.getAttribute("email");
    return invites.findByEmail(email).stream()
            .map(invite -> {
                return invite.wedding;
            }).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList<Wedding>::new));
}
```

This successfully returns a list of weddings. However, on the site you can select one wedding and choose to invite more people to said wedding. The next view on the site asks for the information present in the invite object (String username, String email address, etc.) However, I'm not sure how to reference the wedding I'm "inside" so as to make the association between the invite and the correct wedding. The subsequent route is currently written as so, and adds the invite to the database, and then critically makes the correct association between invite and wedding, then returns a list of wedding -specific invites in order to show everyone who's invited to the wedding:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/create-guest", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public List <Invite> guestList(@RequestBody Invite invite){
    Wedding wedding = weddings.findOne(Integer.valueOf(?)); 
    //unsure how to get weddingid here...
    wedding.invite = invite;
    invites.save(invite);
    return (List) wedding.invite;
}
```

How am I going to get the wedding id? I can't store it in the session. Is there a way I can reference the wedding I'm inside of currently? I can't set it in the previous page, so I can't pull it out in the later page. My front end colleague (using angular) says he can pass me the wedding id inside the invite object, but the fields within my object class won't allow it. My question is: How can I pass the weddingId of the chosen wedding to this subsequent invite page?

Comment: Pass it in the path, or use another object as request body, that allows passing the required information.

Comment: Why not add a unique id to each wedding in the constructor for Wedding? In the Wedding class, you can have a static field of type AtomicInteger that gets incremented in a thread-safe manner. You can then just pass the wedding id as a parameter to the constructor of an Invite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming your using Spring MVC based on your annotations.

You can use a path variable. So instead of posting to /create-guest for wedding id 123 you post to /create-guest/123. You can then use the @PathVariable annotation to access that like so.

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/create-guest/{weddingId}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public List <Invite> guestList(@PathVariable(value="weddingId") String weddingId, @RequestBody Invite invite){
    Wedding wedding = weddings.findOne(Integer.valueOf(weddingId)); 
    wedding.invite = invite;
    invites.save(invite);
    return (List) wedding.invite;
}
```

Just a suggestion if you are creating a RESTful web service. I'm no expert on REST convention but I would think it would be more "REST like" for you to have the url as follows:

/wedding/123/guest

If you post to that URL then it should create a guest for wedding id 123.

Obviously this is convention and not a requirement. It will functionally work either way, but other developers may find your api easier to use if you follow REST convention.